# Can't check the type of web.config

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn

This used to work with VS2010 and VisualSVN 3.  I updated to VS2012 and now when I try to do a SVN `Show Differences for Web.config` I get the following error:

`Can't check the type of C:\thepath\web.config`

I can compare the transformations of web.config so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: I don't get the error with Web.config (VisualSVN 3.0.2 and Visual Studio 2012 RTM). I can recommend you to contact VisualSVN Support Team to solve this (support@visualsvn.com).

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the bug is fixed in VisualSVN 4.0 and newer. [VisualSVN 4.0.1 changelog](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/#v4.0.1):

> - Fixed: 'Can't check the type of' error sometimes occurs when opening
>     built-in Diff window in Visual Studio 2013.